# OSX: Disable process startup disabling on crash

Tags: crash

I'm on OSX 10.14.4 (18E226). I use a 3rd-party application that crashes about once a day. Every time it crashes I restart it, with little impact. But it seems like after 5 (?) crashes, OSX helpfully disables the process from starting, until I logout and login. How do I disable this OS behaviour?

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: What application are you referring to? Is it more like a service or an app?

Comment: It's actually an input method, installed under `/Library/Input Methods/` and invoked from the title bar through the Input menu (I think that's what it's called).